# Trigonometric eq.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math

The equation $3\sin(x)+4\cos(x)=5$ is well-known. The equation $3\sin^m(x)+4\cos^n(x)=5$ where $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers is much more interesting..

I would like to see a nice, elementary solution for this equation.  Thank you!

Comment: Avoid subjective detail questions.

Comment: You could write the trig functions as linear combinations of $e^{\pm ix}$ and expand using the binomial formula. This will lead to a polynomial equation of degree $2\max(n,m)$ in $e^{ix}$, which might be solvable. This also the only way I know to solve the original equation ($n=m=1$).

Comment: @MPW - If we divide by 5, we get $\frac{3}{5}\sin(x)+\frac{4}{5}\cos(x)=1$, or alternatively $\sin(x+\alpha) = 1$ where $\alpha = \arccos(\frac{3}{5})$.

Comment: Ah, clever. So in general, if the coefficients were $a$ and $b$ rather than $3$ and $4$, you could divide by $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and proceed in a similar fashion, eh?

Comment: You can solve it in another way, for example, if x/2 is different from (2k+1) *pi/2, where k is an integer, you can make the following substitutions: cos(x)=(1-tan^2(x/2))/(1+tan^2(x/2) and sin(x)=(2tan(x/2))/(1+tan^2(x/2)) and you obtain a second degree equation with the substitution tan(x/2)=t

Answer (score 0):

We can restrict our attention to $0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

The case $m=0$ or $n=0$ is easy to solve.

The case $m=n=1$ is well-known, as you mentioned.
In fact, $$3\sin(x)+4\cos(x)\leq5$$
and achieves this maximum at some $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

If $m>1$ or $n>1$, obviously $x=0$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ are not solutions.There do not exist solutions $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ as

$$3\sin^m(x)+4\cos^n(x)< 3\sin(x)+4\cos(x)\leq5$$

since $z^m < z$ for $0<z<1$.

There are no solutions in this case.

Comment: Why restrict only to [0,pi/2]?

Comment: First we restrict ourselves to [0,2pi], as the function is periodic.

There can exist solutions in the other three quadrants if m or n is even, but they correspond to a solution in the first quadrant with the sign(s) changed.

Comment: Theee must me more cases: if m=1 and n=0, if m=1 and n>1 and so on...

Comment: I wasn't really careful with my wording, but m=1, n=0 is in the first case (m=0 or n=0) and m=1 and n>1 is in the last case (m>1 or n>1)